# Is Talend Open Studio completely open source for Enterprise in-house ETL projects?

Tags: open-source, etl

We are considering leveraging Talend Open Studio as Open Source ETL platform. We are currently using SSIS primarily for ETL. We want to save licensing costs by going for Talend Open Studio.

But, is Talend Open Studio, completely open source ? or is there any restrictions to use in Enterprise in-house ETL projects ?

Is Talend Data Fabric, the enterprise version of Talend Open Studio ? Or is there any other Talend Product, which is the enterprise version of Talend Open Studio ?

What are the short comings we will be facing, if we go with Talend Open Studio as complete ETL platform ?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that this site is about recommending software that meets specific requirements – not the other way around. For details, see [Are “Can I use X for Y” questions on-topic?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2816/185) If you can **[edit]** your question in a way reflecting that, please do so and we can reopen it for (new) answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple questions in your query, making it harder to reply fully, though I try to put you in a picture:

**Talend Open Studio** runs on a GPL v2 license, as stated in [this discussion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/95655/can-any-gplv2-licensed-library-be-used-in-a-companys-internal-intranet-applicat#95660) it shouldn't be a problem to run with this one an in-house solution. You can also read a [GPL v2 content](https://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.php) (specifically point 2) which allows such solutions to run free of charge.

Comparing **Enterprise** and open source version, there is a question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116243/what-are-the-differences-between-talend-openstudio-and-enterprise-edition) from which you can partly digest what may be short comings (like missing SVN and job scheduler in open source version) between the two. As always you can overcome this limitations ([job scheduler can become windows scheduled task or cron job in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49233588/talend-open-studio-for-data-integration-todays-date-and-automation), versioning can be done externally). This clearly shows one backdraw: you will be spending more time scripting around processes you create with open source studio compared with the enterprise version so you would need skilled persons for that (which is nowadays most expensive source).

Indeed the **Talend Data Fabric** is now the product name of an enterprise version of a Talend Open Studio, though it looks like there are [other products/components](https://talendforge.org/components/) which you can purchase for enterprise. Sorry I cannot be more precise on this field as I am not using enterprise version, but you should get this information via [contacting sales department](https://www.talend.com/contact-sales/) or asking directly in their [support forum](https://talendforge.org/).

Hopefully I made this a bit clearer.

Comment: Thanks Kube. your answer was very helpful. Thanks again.